# Allow public use of functions without giving them database control

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, functions

I came up with a set of functions that I would like to be accessed from a variety of places.  SQL seemed like the best place for this due to accessibility, but I receive this error when trying to use them with a user with only the `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader` permissions: "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object"... etc etc

[image]

I want to pass a date and return other dates.  Apparently I can't just

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_Acct_Day_One] ('1/3/2015')
```

Any way I can do this without granting `db_owner` to the user?

Comment: [GRANT EXECUTE ON ... TO ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx)

Comment: I think functions actually need EXECUTE permissions, but yeah @JohnM is right just grant rights.

Comment: I was hunting for a setting, did not suspect a scripted solution.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to grant rights to use the function.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON Function to UserOrRole
```

Comment: I did this:  `GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO user`, works like a charm.

Comment: That'll work as well, as long as you are OK with them being able to execute every stored procedure and function within the dbo schema.